# How can I fix my jumbled x-axis labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a plot in which the x-axis labels are not uniform. Using axis.text.x = element_text(), I rotated the labels -45 degrees and moved them up at vjust = 1. However, the words on the x-axis themselves are jumbled, and each individual label does not seem uniformly rotated. How can I fix this?

First, the letters seem to be unevenly spaced. Note "nh" in Eisenhower, "Ca" and "rt" in Carter, and "Bu" in W_Bush. Second, the words on the label themselves are not evenly angled, and it seems especially noticeable from Carter to W_Bush.

[image: can be found here]

Code:

```
bp <-
  ggplot(df1, aes(
  x = df1$President,
  y = df1$Count,
  fill = df1$President
)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
  angle = -45,
  hjust = 0,
  vjust = 1
)) + labs(
  title = "Executive Orders Issued by President",
  subtitle = "After World War II",
  x = "President",
  y = "Count"
) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that your `angle` and `vjust` haven't done exactly what you asked for? What do you expect/want it to look like?

Comment: In your ggplot code, remove all instances of `df$`. The data frame name should not be restated within `aes`. Only bare column names should be used.

Comment: @kevin.arseneau First, the letters seem to be unevenly spaced. Note "nh" in Eisenhower, "Ca" and "rt" in Carter, and "Bu" in W_Bush. Second, the words on the label themselves are not evenly angled, and it seems especially noticeable from Carter to W_Bush. I should have clarified that in my original question; thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @eipi10 done, thanks! However, it still did not solve my problem.

Comment: The issue may be with the fonts or graphics device on your local machine. An alternative: use `coord_flip` to plot horizontal bars, so names are on the y-axis with no need for rotation. Also, I don't think fill color by president adds anything to the chart.

Comment: @neilfws the issue ended up being with my local machine; I ran it again on my MBP instead of the desktop and it worked out. Additionally, I agree that the labels being on the y-axis is a more effective way to present the data, and I was just messing around with the fill by color and forgot to/never took it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would use `coord_flip` to place the names on the y-axis, avoiding the need for rotation. I'd also use a single color for the bars and consider reordering.

```
# Example data:

presidents <- structure(list(President = c("George Washington", "John Adams", 
                                           "Thomas Jefferson", "James Madison", 
                                           "James Monroe", "John Quincy Adams", 
                                           "Andrew Jackson", "Martin van Buren", 
                                           "William Henry Harrison", "John Tyler"), 
                             Number = c(8, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 12, 10, 0, 17)), 
                             row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
                             class = "data.frame", 
                             .Names = c("President", "Number"))

presidents %>% 
    ggplot(aes(reorder(President, Number), Number)) + 
      geom_col(fill = "skyblue3") + 
      coord_flip() +
      labs(x = "President")
```

[image]